# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y' for bullet shooting system

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this bit of code, it says that I have an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'
```

I call the class and added them to a group:

```
kunai = Kunai()
kunai_sprites = pg.sprite.Group() #puts all the kunai sprites into a group
```

Here is the class:

```
#throwing projectile (kunai)
class Kunai(pg.sprite.Sprite): #creating the kunai class
    def __init__(self, x, y): #initialising the kunai
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((10,20))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.velocity = 35
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centrex = x

#drawing a circle which will determine the throwing range of the kunai
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.velocity #the kunai moves at set speed
        if self.rect.bottom < 0: #if the sprite crosses 
            self.kill() #it removes the sprite
```

Comment: Your own code doesn't pass in any `x` and `y` arguments to your `Kunai()` class. What did you hope `Kunai()` do without values for your two parameters?

Comment: Since the issue is trivial, basic, and straightforward, I’m voting to close this under typo/can’t be reproduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do.

```
kunai = Kunai(x,y)
```

Like the error says, you are missing two arguments in your initialization.